# HTML CSS Active Class on Nav Bar using Javascript scrollspy and Bootstrap Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Clicking on my first nav bar option scrolls to the correct section on the html page fine, however does not change the colour of the navbar text to orange. Clicking on the second nav bar option, scrolls to the correct section, this time it changes the colour of the first navbar text to orange but not the active nav bar. Clicking on the third nav bar option, scrolls to the correct section, this time it changes the colour of the second navbar text to orange but not the active one. I am trying to activate scrollspy to add active class to the navbar items on scroll. This doesnt seem to be working as it looks like the previous nav bar is the active one which its not.

Javascript:

```
  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 57
  });
```

CSS:

```
        #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link.active, #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link:focus.active {
        color: #f05f40 !important;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Web Designer & Database Developer</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#skills">Skills</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

 <section class="bg-primary" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading text-white">About me!</h2>
                    <img class="img" src="img/a.jpg" />
                    <hr class="light my-4">
                    <p class="text-faded mb-4">Example</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-light btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#skills">Get Started!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
.....
<body>
```

[On skills section but highlighted about from nav bar in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRcMZ.png)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me

Comment: @ZimSystem - with my code above? It doesnt work for me. See attached image to original question. I am on the skills section but its highlighted About in orange. I am expected it to highlight Skills in orange as I am on that section.

Comment: Then you'll need to post the code that reproduces the issue in the question, or create a working snippet

Comment: Seems to work via codepen but not on my website. I will try figure out the difference.